# F# and UdpClient reciver

Tags: f#, udp

I am creating UDP receiver in f# using .Net UdpCLient class and it looks simple:

```
let Start (ip: IPAddress, port : int32) : Async<unit> = 
    async {
        try
            let endpoint = IPEndPoint(ip, port)
            use receivingClient = new UdpClient();
            receivingClient.Client.Bind(endpoint)
            let! receiveResult = receivingClient.ReceiveAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
            let receiveBytes = receiveResult.Buffer
            printfn "%A" receiveBytes 
        with | ex -> raise (ex)
    }
```

And to keep it alive I am using another property that uses rec function in it and it looks like:

```
let Watcher (ip: IPAddress, port : int32) : unit =
    let rec listenerWatcher () = 
        async {
            try
                do! Start (ip, port)
                return! listenerWatcher() 
            with | :? UdpClientDisposedException ->
                return ()
        }        
    listenerWatcher() |> Async.Start
```

and call with type is simple:

```
UdpReceiver.Watcher (ip, port) (* where UdpReceiver is module name *)
```

My problem is that I am only receiving first incoming package, like listener is shutting down after receiving first one, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your problem is that you are sending packages too fast. After receiving the first package, it takes time to start again the receiver, but in the meanwhile the sender is still sending the next packages.

Not sure what is your exact intention, but I think you should start (setup) the receiver only one time, then repeatedly receive the incoming packages, and only restart the receiver when something wrong happens (exceptions are thrown).

By the way, your code is not really idiomatic in F#, you should:

- Prefer separated parameters over tuples, it increases the chance of using currying.
- Use type annotation only when needed, it makes code shorter.
- Name functions so that they are verbs not nouns, and use camelCase style.

I would rewrite your code as below:

```
let start (ip: IPAddress) port =
    let endpoint = IPEndPoint (ip, port)
    let receivingClient = new UdpClient ()
    receivingClient.Client.Bind endpoint
    let rec loop () = async {
        printfn "Waiting..."
        let! receiveResult = receivingClient.ReceiveAsync () |> Async.AwaitTask
        let receiveBytes = receiveResult.Buffer
        printfn "Receive: %A" receiveBytes
        return! loop ()
    }
    loop ()

let watch ip port =
    let rec loop () =  async {
        try
            return! start ip port
        with ex ->
            printfn "Error: %s" ex.Message
            return! loop ()
    }        
    loop ()

// in main function or somewhere:
watch ... ... |> Async.Start...
```